# Proper self-convolution notation

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

[Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) is a mathematical operation on two functions ($f$ and $g$) to produce a third function that expresses how the shape of one is modified by the other. Convolution is defined as follows

$$(f*g)(t)\triangleq \ \int _{-\infty }^{\infty }f(t-\tau )g(\tau )\,d\tau$$

How to denote the self convolution of function $f$ ? In both cases, discrete and infinitesimal.

Comment: You don't simply mean $f*f$, do you?  I think I've seen $f^{*n}$, for the $n$-fold convolution, but I'd explain the notation before I used it.

Comment: I thought about it, but still in doubt, may be you have some examples in manuscripts ?

Comment: Diaconis uses it on, for example, p.25 of his _Group Representations in Probability and Statistics_.  I'm sure I've seen it elsewhere, too.

Comment: yes, I see it, and have you seen somewhere notation $f*f$?